# event auto unbind when Web worker terminate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-worker, worker

I use web worker in my project: one simple question is when ever we terminate the web worker event auto unbind from worker or not:

```
worker = new Worker("scripts/workers/clockTime-worker.js");
worker.addEventListener("message", onMessage);

function onMessage(evt) {
   //------
}

worker.terminate();
```

is message event auto unbind from worker or not?

Comment: Try debugging by dispatching an event. `worker.dispatchEvent(e) ` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 2):

No, the message event is still bound to the worker object.

You can remove the event using the removeEventListener() property of the worker object or, since you're probably done with the worker anyway, set the worker object to null to ensure it is garbage collected.

Here is a test you can use to ensure this on your platform:

```
var worker = new Worker( URL.createObjectURL( new Blob([''])));
var e = new MessageEvent('message');

function test() { console.log('Event fired') }

worker.addEventListener('message', test);
worker.dispatchEvent(e); //Event fired

worker.terminate();
worker.dispatchEvent(e); //Event fired
```

I'm getting the same results in chrome and firefox.

Comment: *"No, the message event is still bound to the worker object."* Citation?

Comment: Well, the code wasn't there when I asked the question; you just made an unsupported statement. *Now* it's a decent answer (would be better if you cited the fact the spec doesn't say handlers are removed). That code shows that it would be observable if the implementation removed handlers on termination of the worker. So since the spec doesn't say it does, it wouldn't be reasonable for an implementation to do so.